# Springboot + Drools, java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal class for global

Tags: spring-boot, drools

Hi I'm checking out some Drools tutorials with Springboot. And I believe I configured properly since the integration tests worked. Once that is done I used the method that was tested in a `@RestController` annotated class method. When I made the service call through browser I'm getting this exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal class for global. Expected [com.model.SomeObj], found [com.model.SomeObj].`, when I checked further it was being triggered by `kieSession.setGlobal("objRes",objRes);`. Could someone lead me in the right direction? Because there aren't any compilation issues in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate question: [Illegal class for global expected com.package.sameobj found com.package.sameobj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676294/illegal-class-for-global-expected-com-package-sameobj-found-com-package-sameobj)

Solution: Remove the hot deployment, you have to remove the next dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I hadn't added this dependency, still got it.

Comment: Create a new project, and move everything, it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without any sample of the code you are using, but the error sounds like you have conflicts in your classpath.

Check if you don't have multiple definitions of the class `com.model.SomeObj` in your app.

If you are running the Drools session in a different app (i.e. The KIE Server), make sure you have the same version of the `com.model.SomeObj` class in both apps (client and KIE Server).

Hope it helps,