# Illegal class for global expected com.package.sameobj found com.package.sameobj

Tags: java, spring, drools

I'm integrating Spring with Drools but I have a problem with the global variables. When I run my code as Java Application there are not problems but if I run my code as Spring Application I got Illegal class for global expected com.package.sameobj found com.package.sameobj Error

Running as Java Application, everything ok:

```
package com.softarts.app;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.softarts.app.logic.Embargo;
import com.softarts.app.logic.Entidad;
import com.softarts.app.services.SystemExpertConfiguration;
import com.softarts.app.services.SystemExpertService;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SystemExpertConfiguration.class);
        SystemExpertService systemExpertService= (SystemExpertService) context.getBean(SystemExpertService.class);
        String s=systemExpertService.calculateEmbargo();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Running as Spring Application, I get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal class for global. Expected [com.softarts.app.systemexpert.datos.DataAmount], found [com.softarts.app.systemexpert.datos.DataAmount].
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.setGlobal(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1202)
    at com.softarts.app.services.SystemExpertService.calculateEmbargo(SystemExpertService.java:28)
    at com.softarts.app.controllers.DocumentController.uploadMultipleFiles(DocumentController.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code,

```
package com.softarts.app.services;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieModule;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.softarts.app.services")
public class SystemExpertConfiguration {
    public static final String drlFile = "reglas.drl";

    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(drlFile));
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();

        return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());        
    }
}
```

and,

```
package com.softarts.app.services;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.softarts.app.systemexpert.datos.DataAmount;
import com.softarts.app.systemexpert.model.Cuenta;

import com.softarts.app.systemexpert.enumeraciones.*;

import com.softarts.app.logic.Embargo;
import com.softarts.app.logic.Entidad;

@Service
public class SystemExpertService {

    @Autowired
    private KieContainer kContainer;

    public String calculateEmbargo() {
        KieSession kieSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
        DataAmount datos = new DataAmount();
        kieSession.setGlobal("datos", datos);
        ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<>();
        cuentas.add(new Cuenta(TipoCuenta.AHORROS, SubtipoCuenta.BASICA, new BigDecimal(1000000),
                LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 24)));
        Embargo embargo = new Embargo();
        for (Cuenta cuenta : cuentas) {
            kieSession.insert(cuenta);
        }
        kieSession.insert(embargo);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
        kieSession.dispose();
        String informacion = "";
        for (Cuenta cuenta : cuentas) {
            informacion += "->La cuenta de " + cuenta.getTipo() + " de " + cuenta.getSubtipo() + " por un valor de "
                    + cuenta.getMontoEmbargado() + "\n";
            informacion += "  en base a las siguientes leyes:" + "\n";
            for (String regla : cuenta.getReglas()) {
                informacion += "\t" + regla + "\n";
            }
        }
        informacion += "El monto total embargado es: " + embargo.getMontoEmbargado() + "\n";
        informacion += "El monto restante de embargar es: "
                + (embargo.getMontoEmbargar().subtract(embargo.getMontoEmbargado())) + "\n";
        return informacion;
    }
}
```

I call the service from my controller

```
    @PostMapping("uploadMultiple")
public String uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
    if (files.size() == 0) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("info", "Please select a file to upload");
        return "redirect:/docs/carga";
    }
    try {
        // uploadFileService.saveMultipleFiles(files);
        List<Embargo> embargos = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InputStream> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            inputs.add(file.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
            filenames.add(file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[0]);
        }

        List<String> texts = detectMultipleText(inputs);
        int aux = 0;
        for (String text : texts) {
            GrammarModule grammar = new GrammarModule(text);
            Embargo embargo = new Embargo(grammar.getDemandantes(), grammar.getDemandados(), grammar.getCuenta(),
                    grammar.getDireccion(), grammar.getFecha(), grammar.getMonto(), grammar.getOficio(),
                    grammar.getReferencia());
            embargos.add(embargo);

            for (Entidad entidad : embargo.getDemandados()) {
                entidad.setCuenta(DataClass.selectCuentas(entidad.getIdentificacion()));
            }

            //////////////////////////
            //HERE I CALL THE SERVICE/
            /////////////////////////
            ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SystemExpertConfiguration.class);
            SystemExpertService systemExpertService= (SystemExpertService) context.getBean(SystemExpertService.class);
            String s=systemExpertService.calculateEmbargo();
            System.out.println(s);
            // Generando documento de respuesta

            GeneratorModule gen = new GeneratorModule("./src/main/resources/res_templates/Modelo 2.docx",
                    new VariablePattern("#{", "}"));
            gen.generateDocument(embargo, "C:\\Documentos\\" + filenames.get(aux) + ".docx");
            embargo.setDocDir(filenames.get(aux) + ".docx");
            aux++;
        }

        model.addAttribute("embargos", embargos);

        System.out.println("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "result";
}
```

Comment: Please add codes not screenshots

Comment: Edited, now it is code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I remove the hot deployment, I remove the next dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```